# Neo4J Cypher Query find path with nodes that must be in it

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a dynamic way to define a cypher query that finds a path with certain nodes in it?

For Example

I want to find a path containing "A", "C" and "G" in exactly this order, where "A" has to be the first node and "G" the last.
But between these nodes any number of nodes and type of relations can exist.
So, the path "A"-[r]->B-[r]->"C"-[r]->D-[r]->E-[r]->F-[r]->"G" would be a valid path.

Is there a way to write this query so that I don't have to explicitly mention all these nodes?
I don't want to write something like "A"-[r*1..00]->"C"-[r*1..100]->"G", but, for example, provide a list containing ("A", "C", "G").

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why you don't want to write something like:  "A"-[r*1..00]->"C"-[r*1..100]->"G"?

Comment: Because I would like to use it e.g. with Spring Data Neo4J and provide the parameters to an @Query, otherwise I would have to overwrite the default repositories, which I try to avoid.